# How to fix this error with custom kernel function in SVM?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, pattern-recognition

I want to create a classifier based on "Support Vector Machines with Custom Kernels" concept. Here's [a link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/support-vector-machines-svm.html?searchHighlight=SVM#buax656-1) that I have Followed it to create my own classifier.

Before every thing, I have to say That in my project I've utilized [this dataset](http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=85350) which is used for Image Segmentation. As an extra information of my code, I have segmented this dataset into structure like following:

- Number of Train samples for each class: 220.
- Number of Test sample for each class: 110.
- Number of features for each sample: 19.
- Number of classes: 7

My code:

```
%  clc;clear;close all; %// not generally appreciated
tic;
load('dataset.mat');

% When you load this dataset, there are two matrices, data_train which contains my training data with above attribute and data_test is so.
X_train = data_train;
X_test = data_test;

[train_size, feature_size, class_size] = size(X_train);
[test_size] = size(X_test,1);

x = [];
for index=1:class_size
    x=[x;X_test(:,:,index)];
end
X_test = x;

correct_label = [];
for index=1:class_size
    correct_label = [correct_label;index*ones(test_size,1)];
end

g = [];
C = 1;
for i=class_size:-1:1
    for j=1:(i-1)
        train = [X_train(:,:,j);X_train(:,:,i)];
        y = [j*ones(train_size,1);i*ones(train_size,1)];
        svmModel = fitcsvm(train,    y,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','GHI_Kernel');
        group = predict(svmModel, X_test);
        g = [g,group];
    end
end


temp = zeros(size(X_test,1),class_size);
n = size(X_test,1);
for i=1:n
    for j=1:class_size
        temp(i,j) = sum(((g(i,:)==j)')); %'//
    end
end

[val, esm] = max(temp,[],2);
CCR = sum(esm == correct_label)/size(correct_label,1);
error = 1 - CCR;
confusion_matrix = confusionmat(esm, correct_label);
toc;
```

And here is my custom kernel function:

```
function output = GHI_Kernel(u, v)
    beta = 2;
    u=u.^beta;
    v=v.^beta;
    test = min(u,v);
    output = sum(test,2);
end
```

With this coding, I think there are no problems with my implementation, BUT, When I run this code in MATLAB with my customized dataset, I come across with this problem:

```
Error using solve
Function GHI_Kernel errors with the
following message: Matrix dimensions must
agree.

Error in
classreg.learning.impl.SVMImpl.make (line 417 [alphas,active,grad,bias,nIter,...

Error in ClassificationSVM (line 319)
        this.Impl =
        classreg.learning.impl.SVMImpl.make(...

Error in classreg.learning.FitTemplate/fit (line 251)
        obj =
            this.MakeFitObject(X,Y,W,this.ModelParams,fitArgs{:});
Error in ClassificationSVM.fit (line 237) this = fit(temp,X,Y);
Error in fitcsvm (line 279)
obj =
ClassificationSVM.fit(X,Y,varargin{:});

Error in Problem1_svm_one_vs_one (line 31)
svmModel = fitcsvm(train, y,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','GHI_Kernel');
```

As the first edit, I repaired the dataset link with my own not with UCI repository.

Comment: I suggest putting a breakpoint inside your `GHI_Kernel` function and reporting back what the dimensions of `u` and `v` are. It's not very clear from the docs (that you linked to) what the dimensions of the inputs or the output to the kernel function should be.

Comment: @Dan Hello, The input dimension to the kernel function is u=[1*19] and v=[1*19].

Comment: And just to confirm, your `output` is a scalar right? Can you try and use the example `mysigmoid` kernel function and see if the dimensions are the same? Are their `G` and your `output` the same size? Do their `mysigmoid` function also give you an error?

Comment: @Dan, I tested it. the inputs u and v are  vectors and the G is also a scalar same to my input and out of my kernel function.

Comment: And do you get the same error using their function as using yours (I would assume so)?

Comment: @Dan, yes Actually your idea is true :).

Comment: And what are the dimensions of `train` and `y` when you call `fitcsvm`?

Comment: @Dan, train is 440*19 double and y is 440*1 double

Comment: In that case I'm all out of ideas. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

The proper documentation can be found [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html). In particular, for custom kernel functions, it states

> You can set your own kernel function, for example, kernel, by setting
>   'KernelFunction','kernel'. kernel must have the following form:
>
> function G = kernel(U,V)
>
> where:
>
> ```
> U is an m-by-p matrix.
>
> V is an n-by-p matrix.
>
> G is an m-by-n Gram matrix of the rows of U and V.
> ```

So if your kernel function `GHI_Kernel` obtains two 19x1 vectors `u` and `v`, it should return a 19x19 matrix. Right now it looks like it just outputs a 19x1 vector.